# How do I change the port in a (legacy) URL object and stringify it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

I'm trying to change (or add) a port value in a given URL string in Node.js.

```
https://localhost:8080/index.html?query=value => https://localhost:9090/index.html?query=value

or

https://localhost/index.html?query=value => https://localhost:9090/index.html?query=value
```

Having to support Node 6 still, I am trying to use [the legacy URL API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/url.html#url_legacy_url_api) like this:

```
> var parsed = url.parse('https://localhost:8080/index.html?query=value');
undefined
> parsed.port = '9090'
'9090'
> url.format(parsed)
'https://localhost:8080/index.html?query=value'
```

This seems to be due to the fact that [`url.format`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/url.html#url_url_format_urlobject) does the following:

> Otherwise, if the urlObject.host property value is truthy, the value
>   of urlObject.host is coerced to a string and appended to result.

Which led me to do the following:

```
> var parsed = url.parse('https://localhost:8080/index.html?query=value');
undefined
> delete parsed.host
true
> parsed.port = '9090'
'9090'
> url.format(parsed)
'https://localhost:9090/index.html?query=value'
```

which does what I want, but feels very hacky and I am unsure about possible side effects of doing that.

Is there a simpler and more idiomatic way of changing the port in a URL string without having to resort to Regexes and the likes?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`URL`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_constructor_new_url_input_base) API - though it may not be supported on older versions of Node. For older versions you can use polyfills such as [`url-parse`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-parse)

**Example:**

```
var url = new URL("https://localhost:8080/index.html?query=value")
url.port = "9090"

var newUrl = url.toString()
// "https://localhost:9090/index.html?query=value
```

Comment: As stated in the answer I still need to support Node 6 and cannot use the WHATWG URL API but need to stick to the legacy one for now.